# Django-gaurdian or Django-rulez for object-level permissions

Tags: django

I am in the process of implementing a row-level (object-level) security package for a django project I am working on.  Django-gaurdian and django-rulez appear to be the most active packages available to implement this.

Has anyone done a comparison of the two, or have you used one or the other?  Please give me any feedback good or bad about either.  Django-rules has the nice feature of storing some information in memory to minimize database load, have you run into any problems with that feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without specific questions it's difficult to make a recommendation. I can say I've used Django-Rules for a couple projects and found the structure to be fairly easy to manage.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is that django-guardian maintains a table where you can add totally arbitrary permissions, whereas django-rules and django-rulez (the latter being a fork of the first one) primarily deduct permission from method calls (`MyModel.can_edit(user)`).

Both methods have their advantages and disadvantages, which one to prefer depends on your usage scenario:

- If your permissions can always be calculated from some other values (for example: "Every user has to be able to edit his/her own uploads"), then django-rule[s|z] would be better suited. You'll spare the overhead, and don't have to care about creating the necessary permission entries whenever you create an object
- If your permissions are totally arbitrary (for example, you need Facebook-like privacy settings for every individual object), then django-guardian would be the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

As at May 2012, it seems that Django-Guardian is beter maintained and documented than Django-Rulez.  It's also more widely used.  I had to make this decision myself, and based on those factors alone, I decided to go with Django-Guardian.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this grid can help you to compare both of them:

http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/

Comment: Thanks.  I have already looked through that.  I am interested in more of the details in how they are implemented, and any bugs which were encountered along the way.